# Publishing in Visual Studio 2017 failing for .NET Core projects

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, publishing

I have a problem with publishing in Visual Studio 2017. For Web Deploy, in publishing, I fill all the fields out correctly, and when I press "Validate Connection", a green symbol appears and everything in Authentication is okay.

However, when I click the publish button for Web Deploy, publishing fails and Visual Studio says:

> could not authorize, make sure you are using the correct username ..."

I have this problem only for .NET Core applications. How I can fix this problem?

> Publish has encountered an error. Build failed. Check the Output window for more details. A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
>
> "C:\Users\Aminpour\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5249.tmp"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes

Comment: Could you also maybe tell the exact error code, not "could not authorize, make sure "u" are using correct username"